# iOS - setting text of UITextView throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, exc-bad-access

I have a `UITextView` which I have created programmatically in the following code:

```
NSLog(@"creating the first blurb");
blurb = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[blurb setText:total];
blurb.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

where `blurb` is defined as a `UITextView` in the `@interface`.

Here's where I'm having the problem:

`total` is an `NSString` that is defined to get the text from a `.txt` file from a specified domain.
It is mutated as:

```
 NSString *url = @"https://sites.google.com/site/paloaltoapps/tbnappsource-password-blackr3d/Updates.txt";
 NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
 total = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

However, when I run the code, I get an instance of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` thrown at the `setText:` line of the top code block.

I have tried printing `total` out using an `NSLog` statement, and that seems to work just fine.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: change blurb from uitextfield to uitextview

Comment: Sorry, it is, that was just a typo

Comment: try this... May be it lose reference......total = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]copy];

Comment: It worked! would you like to put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You should add that as `@property` and use it. Otherwise it will be released before you use it. A `copy` is not suggested in this case. That got a different use than this. Probably a `retain` would have been better if you are not using ARC.

Comment: @ACB +1 retain worked too. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeeter, You should go through this, http://petermcintyre.com/2011/09/19/declared-properties-in-objective-c/ to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... May be it lose reference......

```
total = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]copy];
```

Comment: let me see if I have it right... `copy` allows you to copy the reference, and set the value of `total` to the copied reference instead of the actual value?

Comment: It did. I'm just trying to understand why it's solved the problem and what this extra bit does for my code.

Comment: actuall some times it occured and lose its reference thats why we used copy and retain to retain the value.......... but I can't understand why downvote to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to create an NSString and assign the text to that. And then you can try to print the NSString and see if that works. Just a suggestion.

Comment: that's what `total` is for. I assign `total` the value that is returned by `stringWithContentsOfURL:` and then try to set the value of `blurb` to that. It prints out the correct value, but throws the exception when trying to set the text.