# UITextView throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview

I've created a `UITextView` instance and I'm trying to set its font:

```
UITextView *dummy = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
dummy.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];//self.font;
```

However, at that second line, I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, hitting continue execution doesn't do anything. It still hangs at the same line forever, with no error message at the console. It also used to throw at `self.font` too (I'm using the code inside a working `UILabel` and its `font` is a valid font object). Why am I getting this error?

**UPDATE:** I've also tried `setText:` it also throws the same too. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: have you tried: `[dummy setFont:size:];`?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela `UITextView` doesn't have a `setFont:size:` method.

Comment: Is it real code? (If you set allocated UITextField to weak pointer, then system will release it)

Comment: @AndrewRomanov yes, copy/pasted from my project.

Comment: :) indeed, what about this ["related" post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018419/ios-setting-text-of-uitextview-throws-exc-bad-access?rq=1) it looks similar.

Comment: What do say NSZombies?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela found the answer. it wasn't the related post, rather an initializer problem.

Comment: NSZombies says: "I want to eat your brain" :)

Comment: @Larme zombies were enabled, but they didn't say anything at all, which was also interesting. anyway, found the problem. posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
UITextView *textview =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textview.frame=CGRectMake(200, 10, 500, 50);

//To make the border look very close to a UITextField
[textview.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[textview.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
textview.delegate=self;

//The rounded corner part, where you specify your view's corner radius:
textview.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textview.clipsToBounds = YES;
[textview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:11]];
[textview setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[textview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

I've tried `[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame textContainer:nil];` instead of `[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];` and it worked. I don't understand why the other method didn't work, and this one works even though I'm using `nil` as the `textContainer`.

Comment: Did you try, with your first code that crashed, to clean the project and then installing again? Sometimes it works for me.

Comment: @DavidBemerguy I haven't. But it's solved now. Thank you anyway. It's probably a problem with designated initializers.